# Why does @WebMvcTest not load Controller-Advices into the Application-Context?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit, spring-test, spring-mvc-test

Hello
in my parameterized junit5-test i get a NestedServletException until i add the
**@ContextConfiguration**-Annotation above my test class in which i reference my custom exception handler that is annotated with @ControllerAdvice. In  it i have methods annotated with @ExceptionHandler(ExceptionXY.class) for all exceptions i want to handle in a certain way.
Example that throws NestedServletException

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = SomeController.class)
@WithMockUser("123@domain.de")
class SomeControllerIntegrationTest {
     
    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource({"1000,-100",
                "100,1000000",
                "-8,500",})
    void getInfoForSomething_invalidInputCheck_Status400(int valA, int valB){
            //act
mockMvc.perform(get("v1/anApiEndpoint/"+valA+"/furtherInformation/"+valB+"/getBirthday"))
             .andExpect(status().isBadRequest)
...
```

***Throws Exception :org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: SomeDto.valA: must be less than or equal to 10***

```
    @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
    @WebMvcTest(value = SomeController.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = {SomeExceptionHandler.class, SomeController.class, SomeService.class})
    @WithMockUser("123@domain.de")
    class SomeControllerIntegrationTest {
         
        @ParameterizedTest
        @CsvSource({"1000,-100",
                    "100,1000000",
                    "-8,500",})
        void getInfoForSomething_invalidInputCheck_Status400(int valA, int valB){
                //act
    mockMvc.perform(get("v1/anApiEndpoint/"+valA+"/furtherInformation/"+valB+"/getBirthday"))
                 .andExpect(status().isBadRequest)
    ...
```

***Throws no Exception and returns 400 like expected.***

Now i read that @WebMvcTest should add the ControllerAdvices (in this case *SomeExceptionHandler.class*) but it seems not to happen in my case. Why do i have to configure the context myself and is there a way to do it without that ContextConfiguration-Annotation

**UPDATE:** The custom exception handler is in another starter that i have added in my pom.xml maby this leads to that error.

Comment: it's no different than your approach, but if you don't like the annotation you can go with      
MockMvcBuilders
            .standaloneSetup(SomeController.class)
            .setControllerAdvice(new SomeExceptionHandler())

Comment: @hovanessyan Can you maby explain why only one Controller Advice is added by default ? I found out that my other Controller Advice is added when i dont add the @ ContextConfiguration annotation.

Comment: How do you activate the custom exception handler from the other starter during runtime? Is it auto-configured or part of a `@Configuration` class?

Comment: It is in an ```@configuration```class @rieckpil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `@WebMvcTest`, only MVC-related components get populated in the sliced Spring Test Context. As you've mentioned that you activate the custom exception handler from a different starter using `@Configuration`, that won't be populated by default as `@WebMvcTest` doesn't look for `@Configuration` classes.

You can still manually add your configuration using `@Import(NameOfYourConfig.class)` on top of your test class to enrich the sliced Test Context with further beans.

For more information, consider the [relevant section in the Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.spring-mvc-tests) or this [Spring Boot Test slice overview](https://rieckpil.de/spring-boot-test-slices-overview-and-usage/).

Comment: Thank you very much. Am i right that import would not consider @conditional? Therefore if i need it should i use ```@ImportAutoConfiguration```

Comment: you're welcome. Yes, that should be the case.